# How to toggle placeholdertextcolor value in textinput?

Tags: react-native

I want to make a dark mode and light mode, on dark mode I want the placeholdertextcolor white, on light mode I want it dark. To make this happen I've tried a if/else in placeholdertextcolor itself, I've also tried to do it with a function as shown below in the code.

I use Switch from react-native that returns a true or false. On true execute first style in statement, on false execute second style in the statement. These placeholderTextColor are in the texinput.

```js
// First try
const toggle = this.state.switchValue;
<TextInput
 style={textInput}
 onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
 placeholder={'Password'}
 placeholderTextColor={toggle === true ? styles.darkColor : styles.whiteColor}
 value={this.state.password}
/>

// Second try by doing it through a function
test = () => {
    return toggle === true ? styles.darkColor : styles.whiteColor
};
<TextIn...
placeholderTextColor={() => this.test()}
/>

// Third try. From the statement above I get an object, so I get the color (string ("#444")). But still get same error.
placeholderTextColor={toggle === true ? JSON.stringify(styles.darkColor.color) : JSON.stringify(styles.whiteColor.color)}
```

I expect for the placeholder to change color based on the state of the switch. But all I get are errors; Warning: Failed prop type: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop **and** Invalid prop `placeholderTextColor` supplied to `TextInput`: function. Is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: I think we need to find out more about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#placeholdertextcolor) of TextInput "placeholderTextColor" should accept "color" prop and you are using style .

**Try this**

```
const toggle = this.state.switchValue;
<TextInput
 style={textInput}
 onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
 placeholder={'Password'}
 placeholderTextColor={toggle === true ? "black" : "white"}
 value={this.state.password}
/>
```

Comment: Wauw, you're right. I don't get why the code of mine didn't work, because that returns also a string with the colorcode, well if it works it works. Thanks man!